# Save in Drupal 6 administration very slow

Tags: drupal-6

When I save something in an administration page in Drupal, for example when I save on

```
http://drupal62/admin/build/modules
```

it takes a very long time. It says,

```
Executed 2980 queries in 51606.38 milliseconds. Queries taking longer than 5 ms and queries executed more than once, are highlighted. Page execution time was 52547.06 ms.
```

I know that this question is vague. I don't think is is a MySQL problem. Maybe you have seen it before.

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4115/admin-configuration-page-update-module-page-slow-to-load, it's very, very likely to be related

Comment: hello Clive, Thank you very much. But it didn't solve my problem. I used xhprof and I saw that the way Drupal caches is changed in Drupal 7 and in Drupal 7 the administration pages are OK. I don't know. But again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem as you and although it's not exactly a MySQL problem, it's related to Drupal 6 database optimisation. Are you running on localhost? If so, then could you give some more information as to OS, and if you're using XAMPP, WAMP, etc.

I am currently running Drupal 6 on Windows 7 and WAMP Server with none of the lag you're experiencing. If it's the same issue, I've got it documented so will let you know the config changes.

Answer (score 0):

You're right it's too vague to be fully answered here without more information.

It will depend of course of your specific configuration, of the modules you use, how many of them, your PHP memory limit, possible errors in your database.

A common debugging method is simply to disable most, if not all the modules and re-enable them one by one, until you can single out what goes wrong. You can also start by clearing all caches , then again depending on the modules you're using.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Drupal 6 works well with MyISAM tables, Drupal 7 with InnoDB. I don't know why, but that's it.